# C#/C++ interop - Need help defining my data structure

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

I am working on a C# app that is trying to use functionality provided via a C++ DLL. I am having a bit of a hard time getting the DLLImport definitions to work right at the moment.

Here's the C++ side of the equation:

```
struct Result
{
    FLOAT   first;
    FLOAT   second;
};

struct ResultData
{
    UINT            uint1;
    UINT            uint2;
    Result          result;
    Result*         pResults;
};

#define DllImport __declspec(dllimport)    
extern "C"
{
    DllImport HRESULT APIENTRY Process(const PCWSTR FileName, const PCWSTR logfileFileName, const PCWSTR DataFileName, ResultData** ppResults);
    DllImport HRESULT APIENTRY Release(ResultData* pResults);
}
```

On the C# side, here's what I have done so far:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Result
    {
        public float first;
        public float second;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ResultData
    {
        public uint uint1;
        public uint uint2;
        public Result result;
        public Result[] Results;
    }    

        DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
        static extern uint Release(ResultData pResults);

        [DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
        static extern uint Process(string FileName, string logfileFileName, string DataFileName, ref ResultData ppResults);
```

Is this the correct way to do it? The thing I am most concerned about is that pResults member of the ResultData structure. I don't want that copied by value as it will be a large amount of data and I don't want to replicate memory... how can I make sure that doesn't happen?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

The most immediate problem that jumps out at me is the Results member in ResultData.  The native type is a `Result*` but you've translated it as an array.  This may or may not work (can't remember off the top of my head).  What will work though is marshalling it as an `IntPtr` type.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ResultData
{
    public uint uint1;
    public uint uint2;
    public Result result;
    public IntPtr RawResults;
    public Result Results { get { return (Result)Marshal.PtrToStructure(RawResults,typeof(Result)); }
}
```

This is assuming that it's a single value.  If it's more than one value a more complex marshalling will be needed.

Also the native Release method takes a `ResultData*` but you have a simple by value `ResultData` type in the managed signature.  It needs to have the same level of indirection.  You can achieve this by making it a ref param.

```
DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
static extern uint Release(ref ResultData pResults);
```

Comment: Hummm, single value == one value, afaict. You missed 'more than' in the last sentence I presume

Comment: @Vinko, correct.  It's amazing how well it reads to yourself until someone points out the obvious inconsistency :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep the interface to pure C primitive types, you won't have to do any marshalling.  This will save you a lot of heartache.